# Bing Imagery API over HTTPS

Tags: jquery, ajax, bing-maps

Bing Imagery REST services supports HTTPS protocol. Using jQuery AJAX, a call to this API returns resource objects with HTTP reference. This gives the following error:

> Mixed Content: The page at XYZ was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://ecn.t0.tiles.virtualearth.net/tiles/r03210.jpeg?g=3451&mkt=en-US&shading=hill'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Is is a Bing issue? Or is there any parameter to be passed in AJAX call to get the response as HTTPS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Bing Maps AJAX control be sure to add "&s=1" to the end of the script reference.

Comment: Its clearly mentioned that I am using Bing Imagery REST services and not Bing Maps.

Comment: It still wasn't clear what you were trying to do. In any case add the following parameter to your URL "&uriScheme=https"